# Android Studio shows erros when there are none

Tags: android, android-studio

today when I launched android studio I noticed that every method of any activity is being highlighted as an error. Also, the self reference to the class 'this' is highlighted as an error. The strange thing is when I build and run the project, everything works. So I'm wondering what could be the issue. Cause it's quite annoying to work especially when they are real errors to fix.

Comment: Try to clean and resync the project.

Comment: Thanks!! That solved it.